# How do I handle google_sign_in on flutter for error NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'authentication' was called on null?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

In my emulator when I clicked to sign in with Google it produced this error

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'authentication' was called on null.
```

I was able to resolve the error by signing out of the google account in the emulator and signing in again without issue.

Is this problem specific to the emulator's accounts?  It seems like some type of session expiration if I were to use web terms.

I wanted to know if this could happen on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't added an auth certificate in your android section.

Or you have missed some dependencies and import statements for android.

I was also facing the same issue but able to fix it by this method.

Use this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/
because other methods are a bit tricky.

````
Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Trigger the authentication flow
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

  // Obtain the auth details from the request
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  // Create a new credential
  final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}```
````

Comment: It thinks there's a user because after I go through the Google login screen it seems ok but that value is still null after I click my user.  If the user has just signed in it works.  So there is something expired about the user who is signed into the device.  It's on the android side somehow.

It's going through the sign in process as expected (as presented to the user) but returning null in the app.

Comment: Try to  run this googleSignIn.signInSilently().

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30651#issuecomment-481457075

Comment: Unfortunately still null unless that user is "freshly" signed into the my emulator device; then it's fine.

Comment: I wiped the emulator which seems to have it working for now; theres some communication that must be lost for my google account on the emulator itself

Comment: Yes, you have to note down the steps.